# Bash script: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, terminal, scrapy, cygwin

So, i need to run this **run.sh** file and i could not with windows default **CMD**. 
So i installed **Cygwin64 Terminal** and it acctualy reads the file, but at the end of the reading, it spams an error:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/./run.sh
Starting scraper
Scrape complete, checking movies with imdb
C:\python27\python.exe: can't open file 'check_imdb.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Inside **run.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting scraper"
scrapy runspider cinema_scraper.py -t json --nolog -o - > "movies.json"
echo "Scrape complete, checking movies with imdb"
python check_imdb.py movies.json
```

check_imdb.py is inside run.sh folder.

Answer (score 4):

The file is referenced inside the script as a relative path.

```
python check_imdb.py movies.json
```

Relative means that it does not specify the whole path (starting with /), and is interpreted relative to the current directory, which you can find out with :

```
pwd
```

A path starting with `/` is said to be absolute.

The important thing is to remember a script interprets paths relative to the current directory, not the directory where the script is located.

You could change to the directory of the script before running it, with :

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts
```

But if you do that, then you will need to provide an absolute path on the command line to your `movies.json` file.

Better yet, modify the script to have an absolute path:

```
python /cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/check_imdb.py movies.json
```